# Como retornar os indices que um elemento aparece em uma tupla?

Tags: python, tupla

**Escreva uma função chamada 'posicoes' que recebe como argumentos de entrada
uma tupla e um item, e retorna uma lista contendo todos os índices em que o
item aparece na tupla.
Caso o item nao exista na tupla, deve retornar uma lista vazia.
**
-MEU CÓDIGO

```
tupla = (5, 6, 5, 3, 5)
def posicoes(tupla, item):
    indice = 0
    for i in range(len(tupla)):
      if item in tupla(i):
        indice.append((i))
    
    return indice

print(posicoes(tupla,5))
```

Comment: Você está tentando utilizar o método `.append()` em uma variável que recebe 0, onde define a variável `indice`, deveria ser `indice = []`.

Comment: po, vc tem razão, acabei esquecendo de mudar na hora de postar

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar o índice do item da tupla, você pode utilizar o método `enumerate(tupla)`, ele retorna o valor da tupla junto de seu índice, então se o item for igual sua variável `item`, você acrescenta somente o índice na lista `indice`

O código fica assim:

```py
tupla = (5, 6, 5, 3, 5)
def posicoes(tupla, item):
  indice = []
  for i in enumerate(tupla):
    if i[1] == item:
      indice.append(i[0])

  return indice

print(posicoes(tupla,5))
```

Comment: boa noite, felipe, poderia explicar o porque de 'if i[1] não compreendi o porque do 1'

Comment: Boa noite @ViniciusMota, quando você percorre os itens da tupla com `for i in enumerate(tupla):`, você recebe o valor de `i` como `({índice},{valor})`, e onde `if i[1] == item:` nós queremos comparar somente o valor da tupla e não o índice, e se verdadeira a condição, acrescenta apenas o índice na lista `indice` com `indice.append(i[0])`.  
Teste você mesmo o código somente com `print(i)` após `for i in enumerate(tupla):`

Comment: caraca, compreendi, muito obrigado felipe, agradeço ple ajuda